# Calculate duration in years for multiple variables in a column

Tags: python, pandas, date, duration

I am trying to calculate how long each store has been open in years. Here is an example of the dataset:

| year | store name |
| --- | --- |
| 2000 | Store A |
| 2001 | Store A |
| 2002 | Store A |
| 2003 | Store A |
| 2000 | Store B |
| 2001 | Store B |
| 2002 | Store B |
| 2000 | Store C |

I'm not sure how to calculate the difference in max and min year for each store name as they are all in the same column. Do I put it into a new column using pandas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `groupby`:

```
g = df.groupby('store name')['year']

out = g.max()-g.min()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` and `transform` to create an additional column in the same dataframe.

```
df["years open"] = df.groupby("store name")["year"].transform(lambda x: x.max()-x.min())
```

Comment: Why `transform` and not `agg`? I think broadcast the value to all rows is what is expected?

Comment: `Transform` maintains the level of granularity and adds the necessary information as a new column. I hoped to maintain the data as is and add the necessary info as an additional column

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
out = df.groupby('store name').agg(['min', 'max']).diff(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]
print(out)

# Output
store name
Store A    3
Store B    2
Store C    0
Name: (year, max), dtype: int64
```